# C++ Map as function output in VBA

Tags: c++, vba, map, function

Tengo un código de C++ que me devuelve un mapa. He creado un dll y lo llamo desde un macro de Excel.

Luego, en ese macro, necesito un diccionario `(Scripting.Dictionary)`.

He intentado hacer lo siguiente:

```
Declare Function ExlFunct Lib "direccion" (InputDict As Variant, ByVal a As Integer) As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim a As Integer
Dim InputDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim Out As New Scripting.Dictionary
//creo el dicionario de entrada y le asigno un valor a "a"
Out = ExlFunct (InputDict, a )
```

Me devuelve el siguiente error:

> ```
> Error de compilacion: El argumento no es opcional
> ```

¿Puede deberse el error a problemas entre el map de c++ y el dictionary de vba?¿Como podría solucionarlo?